¿Reproducir un video con la clase Media (vb.net)?
Intento reproducir un video con el siguiente código de vb.net. Se escucha pero no se ve nada. ¿Cómo hago para que se reproduzca el video?:
Imports System.Windows.Media

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim MP As MediaPlayer
  Dim aVideoDrawing As VideoDrawing

  MP = New MediaPlayer()
  MP.Open(New Uri("D:\cielo.mp4", UriKind.Absolute))
  aVideoDrawing = New VideoDrawing()

  aVideoDrawing.Rect = New Rect(0, 0, 100, 150)
  aVideoDrawing.Player = MP

  MP.Play()
End Sub


Hola. Has de agregar el componente de Windows Media Player ( wmp.dll ) al panel de controles de usuario y utilizar los métodos del objeto que tendrás que agregar al formulario. En él, tienes la propiedad controls, con la que manejar el vídeo y su url para reproducir en un control de usuario en el formulario.
